# update values from two table with the same pcode and id

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables named tbl_sales and tbl_rsales.

Lets assume that i have these ff value for "tbl_sales"

```
id | pcode | total |
2  | 12345 | 10    |
3  | 12345 | 10    |
```

Lets assume also that i have these ff value from "tbl_rsales"

```
id | sales_id | total | pcode |
1  | 1        | 20    | 55555 |
2  | 2        | 10    | 12345 | 
3  | 3        | 10    | 12345 |
```

I can easily update data from "tbl_sales" but my problem is that when i update all value by "pcode" from tbl_sales "tbl_rsales" must be update also. but  only those id's from "tbl_sales" that are in "sales_id" from tbl_rsales will update. so in other word. sales_id 1 from "tbl_rsales" will not  update only sales_id 2 and 3 will be update because tbl_sales id and tbl_rsales "sales_id" is the same. it's lil complicated for me.any idea is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE sales, rsales
SET sales.pcode=rsales.pcode
WHERE sales.id=rsales.id
AND id IN(2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

```
UPDATE TBL_SALES , TBL_RSALES
SET //WAHTEVER YOU WANT FROM THE TABLE
WHERE TBL_SALES,PCODE = TBL_RSALES.PCODE
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me sir. but thanks anyway, i get some idea and totally get the result :D