# updating multiple values from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables named "sales" and "rsales" ,

and now i have this ff data from "sales"

```
id | pcode | total | 
2  |  122  |  20   |  
3  |  122  |  20   | 
4  |  321  |  30   |
5  |  321  |  30   |
```

don't wonder why i have duplication of pcode,total,discount, it's simply  because when i "add order" or click my submit button it saves to the tble "sales" in that way like what i have illustrated above. i have this code to share with you how to update my tbl "sales" and it works very well. what i did is that i get the id. let say for example i get the id "1" from "sales" so when i run my query  below it update id "1" but also id "2" because they are the same "pcode" it's obvious to my query. i have no problem updating my tbl "sales"

```
mysql_query("UPDATE sales SET total = '$total_discount' where pcode = '$pcode' ");
```

so my problem is this i have this ff codes to update my tbl "rsales

```
   mysql_query("UPDATE rsales SET total = '$total_discount' ,discount = '$tot'  WHERE   rsales.sales_id IN (SELECT sales.id FROM sales)");
```

what i want is that when i update specific pcode in my tbl "sales" the tbl "rsales" must be update also. so let say for example i update "total" from "sales" by pcode 122., so from 20 i change it to 40 , so my tbl "rsales" must be look like this way

```
id | pcode | total | sales_id|
2  |  122  |  40   |  2      |
3  |  122  |  40   |  3      |
4  |  321  |  30   |  4      |
5  |  321  |  30   |  5      |
```

butmy query is showing me this result. allvrows  updating.i can't update exactly the "total" from "rsales"  pls help me. every help is very helpful.

```
id | pcode | total | sales_id|
2  |  122  |  40   |  2      |
3  |  122  |  40   |  3      |
4  |  321  |  40   |  4      |
5  |  321  |  40   |  5      |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535724/update-values-from-two-table-with-the-same-pcode-and-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below. Also, according from your table layout you're missing the `discount` column, I'm assuming it's in the test database.

```
UPDATE sales AS t1, rsales AS t2
SET t1.total = '$total_discount',
t2.total = '$total_discount',
t2.discount = '$tot'
WHERE t1.pcode = '$pcode'
AND t2.pcode = t1.pcode
```

By the way, you're modifying all rows because of this line:

```
WHERE rsales.sales_id IN (SELECT sales.id FROM sales)
```

Here, you are saying to update `rsales` where `sales_id` is IN (One Of) the `sales.id` fields. You are pulling all `sales.id`'s. If you need to specify what ID specifically, add this to the bottom of the query above:

```
AND t1.id = '$id'
AND t2.sales_id = t1.id
```

Haven't made a mock up of your DB so I haven't tested it.

Comment: wow! unbelievable sir! you get exactly what i am asking even i did or maybe i don't know how   give you the complete details awesome.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to feed the geeks!